# How to append data strings to $http in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Very new to angular and wondering how I append data to my `$http` `GET` request in angular, I have tried the following way which is the same as jQuery but with no success:

```
$http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'twitter_queries.json',
                data: {
                    q: '#tweet
                }
            })
```

**Updated data to params and this solved it:**

```
$http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'twitter_queries.json',
                params: {
                    q: '#tweet'
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $http.get('twitter_queries.json', {q: '#tweet'})
           .success(function(res) {
               ........
            })
           .error(function(error) {
              ...........
            })
```

Comment: hey, doesnt seem to add the query param?

Comment: but this is a standard way.

Comment: im not sure why your way isnt working for me, my request 400s when I try your method